# How can I get user email when logging in through Facebook in parse.com

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform, facebook-authentication

I need to obtain a user email for business purposes in my parse.com application. Is it possible to fetch it during Facebook sign-up/login process?

For example I have the following login code

```
var signupLoginFB = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", {
      success: function(user) {
        //do something on successful login
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        //do something on error
      }
    });
  }
```

I looked at the "user" object passed to the callback, and I didn't see any email there. Should I call some other FB or Parse API to fetch these data?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to make a call to `FB.api()` as follows:

```
var signupLoginFB = function() {
  Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", {
    success: function(user) {
      //do something on successful login
      FB.api('/me', function(me) {
        user.set("displayName", me.name);
        user.set("email", me.email);
        user.save();
        console.log("/me response", me);
      });
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      //do something on error
    }
  });
}
```

You'll see in the console all the fields returned. Note that they'll vary based on what they have decided to share, for example my Facebook profile doesn't include my email as public so it isn't returned in the "/me" call.

Consider also only doing the extra call if it is a new user, ie wrap that code in `if (!user.existed()) {...}`.